# Programmatically instantiate Xtext artefacts

Tags: xtext

Lets assume we have a Xtext grammar like

```
Greeting:
'Hello' name=ID;
```

Then Xtext generates an Interface `Greeting` an a class `GreetingImpl`.
Now I need to programmatically create an instance of a `Greeting` but this seems complicated because all constructors of `GreetingImpl` are `protected`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the default emf factories for that.

```
MyDslFactory.eINSTANCE.createGreeting()
```